# Java: Printing two dimensional array in grid format

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having difficulty figuring out the code to print a two dimensional array in grid format.

```
public class TwoDim {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[][] ExampleArray = new int [3][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                ExampleArray[i][j] = i * j;
                System.out.println(j);
            }   
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change to `System.out.print(ExampleArray[i][j]+" ");` instead of using `println`. And remove `i` from, `System.out.println()`;

Comment: You could try this: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ExampleArray));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `System.out.println(...);`, it prints a newline char (`'\n'`) after the string you intended to print. This should only happen if your line is over (i.e., outside the innest `for` statement). So, your `for` loops should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        ExampleArray[i][j] = i * j;
        System.out.print(ExampleArray[i][j] + ' '); //You can replace ' ' by '\t', if
                                                      //you want a tab instead of a space
    }   
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(s)` prints `s`, then *prints a line return character*. So if you want multiple `print` calls to end up on the same line, you should use `System.out.print(s)` instead.
Additionally, you can use `System.out.println()` (with no argument) to print nothing, but move to the next line. Bringing all of that together:

```
public class TwoDim {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    int[][] ExampleArray = new int [3][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                ExampleArray[i][j] = i * j;
                System.out.print(j + "  ");
            }   
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```